# Formatting dataframe into excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I am doing all of my data manipulation using python and have all the required values in a dataframe.

I am not sure how to format the dataframe into excel in the following format (merged cells for categories, etc) -

Eg DF-

```
Item No   Item Name    Category  Italy Count  Netherlands Count  France Count   Grand Total
      1      Item A  Category 1            5                 10            20            35 
      1      Item B  Category 1            5                 10            20            35
```

Format -

[image]

Comment: Hi, it seems to me that you need to use something like MultiIndex/Advanced indexing(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), and save it using DataFrame.to_excel.

Comment: It might be easier to send the data frame to excel as a standard table of data. Have that on one tab and your report on another tab. Pull the data into the report using the Excel function `SUMPRODUCT`.